# how to check "reference equality" between two range variables

Tags: excel, vba, reference, equality

I am not very experienced in vba, so there seems to be something I'm missing, starting from the basics.

I have a custom class named "imera" in which I include a range property named "date_cell".
When creating a collection of imera's, every imera's date_cell takes a reference to a specific cell in excel.
So now I need to search within the collection by date_cell:

```
Sub searchByDateCell()
    Dim day As imera
    Dim LastMetrisi As Range
    Set LastMetrisi = Range("C27")
    For Each day In imeraCol
        If day.date_cell Is LastMetrisi Then
            'Do something
        End If
    Next day
    Set day = Nothing
End Sub
```

Let me note that the collection is called imeraCol and its declared as public.

Although I have tested by debug.print that in my colection exists an imera with date_cell set to range("C27"), the 'Do something section above, never executes. Does anybody know why is this happening?

Comment: I set LastMetrisi = Range("C27") and I want to search if there is an imera in my collection that has it's date_cell set to Range("C27").

Comment: Why don't you use the property `.address`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Address` with `External` set to `True`.

> External: True to return an external reference. False to return a
>   local reference.

*Note: Be carefull by `Range`, consider fully qualified reference e.g.: `Worksheets(3).Range("C27")`.*

```
Option Explicit

Public imeraCol As Collection

Sub test()

    Dim imera1 As imera
    Set imera1 = New imera
    Set imera1.date_cell = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

    Dim imera2 As imera
    Set imera2 = New imera
    Set imera2.date_cell = Worksheets(2).Range("B1")

    Dim imera3 As imera
    Set imera3 = New imera
    Set imera3.date_cell = Worksheets(3).Range("C27")

    Set imeraCol = New Collection

    ' When creating a collection of imera's,
    ' every imera's date_cell takes a reference to a specific cell in excel.

    imeraCol.Add imera1, "imera1"
    imeraCol.Add imera2, "imera2"
    imeraCol.Add imera3, "imera3"

    searchByDateCell
End Sub

Sub searchByDateCell()
    Dim day As imera
    Dim LastMetrisi As Range

    Set LastMetrisi = Worksheets(3).Range("C27")

    For Each day In imeraCol
        If day.date_cell.Address(external:=True) = LastMetrisi.Address(external:=True) Then
            Debug.Print day.date_cell.Address(external:=True) & " exists in collection"
        End If
    Next day
    Set day = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your points. I'm opening a new question to ask why this is happening